# Erlang Nitrogen tutorial project does not work

Tags: erlang, nitrogen

I'm following the tutorial on the nitrogen project page:
[starter tutorial here](https://nitrogenproject.com/doc/tutorial.md)

and when I point my browser to `localhost:8000` it does not work.
I suspect it is something to do with this following the command:

```
make rel_inets;

/home/david/programming/erlang/nitrogen/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/lib/erlware_commons/src/ec_cmd_log.erl:160:5: ambiguous call of overridden auto-imported BIF error/3
**-** use erlang:error/3 or "-compile({no_auto_import,[error/3]})." to resolve name clash Compiling /home/david/programming/erlang/nitrogen/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/lib/erlware_commons/src/ec_cmd_log.erl failed: ERROR: compile failed while processing /home/david/programming/erlang/nitrogen/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/lib/erlware_commons: rebar_abort make[4]: *** [Makefile:12: compile] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any idea of what is going wrong? Looks to be some clash between function names.
I installed the latest erlang 24.0.1 and I still got the same behaviour.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone have any idea of what is going wrong?

Here is an example...Erlang defines a function `error/2`, known as a BIF or **B**uilt **I**n **F**unction, which can be called like this:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).


go(X, Y) ->
    case X > 10 of
        true -> error(bad_arg, [X, Y]);
        false -> ok
    end,
    io:format("hello\n").
```

In the shell:

```
4> c(a).
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

5> a:go(1, 2).
hello
ok

6> a:go(11, 2).
** exception error: bad_arg
     in function  a:go/2
        called as a:go(11,2)
7>
```

Now, look what happens if you define a function also named `error/2` in your module:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

error(X, Y) ->
   io:format("X = ~w, Y = ~w~n", [X,Y]). 

go(X, Y) ->
    case X > 10 of
        true -> error(bad_arg, [X, Y]);
        false -> ok
    end,
    io:format("hello\n").
```

In the shell:

```
8> c(a).
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported

a.erl:9: Warning: ambiguous call of overridden auto-imported BIF error/2
 - use erlang:error/2 or "-compile({no_auto_import,[error/2]})." to resolve name clash
{ok,a}
```

The warning tells you that if you really meant to call erlang's `error/2`, then you should preceed the function name with the module name in which the function is defined, namely the `erlang` module:

```
case X > 10 of
    true -> erlang:error(bad_arg, [X, Y]);
```

...or, if you want to call your version of `error/2`, then put the module directive:

```
 -compile({no_auto_import,[error/2]}).
```

at the top of your module:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).
-compile({no_auto_import,[error/2]}).

error(X, Y) ->
   io:format("X = ~w, Y = ~w~n", [X,Y]). 

go(X, Y) ->
    case X > 10 of
        true -> error(bad_arg, [X, Y]);
        false -> ok
    end,
    io:format("hello\n").


11> c(a).       
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}
```

Note that the problem in the code is only a `warning`, and when I run my program as originally written, erlang calls the version of `error/2` defined in my module--not the one in the `erlang` module.

The strange thing is: there is no `error/3` defined in the erlang module.

Comment: Thanks @7stud that was very helpful. Maybe there is an error/3 in OTP 24. Please see what I found on line 26 in this file: https://github.com/erlware/erlware_commons/blob/master/src/ec_cmd_log.erl

Comment: The latest  version of Nitrogen was released before OTP 24 and i'm using OTP 24.

Comment: @Bucephalus, The comment on line 25 says:`%% Avoid clashing with error/3  BIF added in Erlang/OTP 24`.  *The latest version of Nitrogen was released before OTP 24 and i'm using OTP 24.* -- Then you have to downgrade your Erlang or alter the Nitrogen source code to include lines like line 26 wherever error/3 is called.

Comment: Thanks @7stud .  I raised this issue in erlang slack and the project manager for Nitrogen said he will address this issue this week. I have plenty of learning to do on Erlang so I will just go onto something else in the mean time and stick with OTP 24. Thanks for your help - it has been very insightful.

Comment: The issue has been fixed.  It was ultimately that Nitrogen depends on qdate, which depends on erlware_commons (but was bound to an older version of erlware_commons).  This has been updated, qdate 0.6.0 is tagged and works with OTP24.